# All mkannotation(s) showing + a new one when tapped

Tags: xcode, annotations, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mapkit

I have a question about MKAnnotation.
I currently have a map with 4 pins each with an annotation badge thing that shows up when the pin is tapped. Only the last pin loaded has the annotation showing.

I was wondering if it is possible first to have all annotations show together.
Second if it is possible to have a second annotation when the pin is tapped, basically replacing the old one.

--> I actually want to have a little icon show up above each (all) pin(s) and when tapped another annotation shows up with some details...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please clarify?  Is "an annotation badge thing" a callout (view that pops up when pin is tapped)?  The "pin" is the "annotation".  Only 1 callout can be open at a time (but there are workarounds).  By "second annotation when pin is tapped, ... replacing old one" do you mean present new view (not create new pin) with details about tapped pin?  May want to focus on one issue at a time and [review docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH1-SW1) for terminology.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for inclarity, yea by annotation badge thing I mean: http://mobiparty.net/ressources/Screenshot.png where it says: your address… is that called a callout? After reading it seems like it is called an annotation view sorry I'm not good with terminology...

I would basically want all of them (from several pins) to show at the same time (the purple pin for example should show one) and if you tap is it should show another one…

Thanks for the help